# Метод slice округляет параметры в меньшую сторону?

Tags: javascript

Дана строка: `vovamzys`.

Нужно вывести два элемента, которые расположены справа и слева от центра (в данном случае буквы `am`). На codewars я нашёл способ сделать это при помощи `slice()`:

```js
const str = "vovamzys";

console.log(str.slice((str.length - 1)/2, str.length/2 + 1));
```

Но ведь begin здесь равен 3,5, а буква `а` входит в выводимый диапазон. На [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) я про это ничего не нашёл.

Comment: Что-то я не увидел в Вашем коде слова `slice`... *begin здесь равен 3,5* Индекс по определению - целый. А вот на параметры такого ограничения нет. Так что тип результата вычисления неявно приводится к целому.

Comment: Извиняюсь, исправил.

Comment: Но разве при округлении 3,5 не должно выходить 4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, Вас интересует где это поведение описано:

Открываем String.prototype.slice() на MDN раздел [спецификации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice#Specifications)

Выбираем последнюю редакцию [ECMAScript 2015](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-string.prototype.slice)

> 21.1.3.16 String.prototype.slice ( start, end )
>   ...

пункт 5

> 5.Let intStart be ToInteger(start).

Находим определение ToInteger

> 7.1.4 ToInteger ( argument )

опять-же пункт 5

> 5.Return the number value that is the same sign as number and whose magnitude is floor(abs(number)).

Ну и так далее...